# Basis of $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $n^2\times n^2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $m_1,..., m_{n^2}$ be $n\times n$ matrices in $M(n,\mathbb{C})$. If we identify them as vectors in $M(n,\mathbb{C})= \mathbb{C}^{n^2}$, we can form an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix $M$ with columns are the $m_1,..., m_{n^2}$. Then how to see $m_1,..., m_{n^2}$ span linearly to $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ iff $M$ has a non-zero determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're doing, and the answer is yes, it does work.

What's happening behind the scenes here? You're taking the standard basis for $M(n, \Bbb{C})$ consisting of matrices with exactly one $1$ entry and $0$s elsewhere (in some order, depending on how you order the entries of your $n^2$ matrices when putting them as columns in your $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix), and converting your $n^2$ matrices into coordinate column vectors in $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$ with respect to this basis.

You're then testing the linear independence of these coordinate vectors by using the Inverse Matrix Theorem, where the matrix formed by placing these coordinate vectors in as columns, has a non-zero determinant if and only if the columns are linearly independent. This means the coordinate vectors are linearly independent, which imply the original vectors (the $n \times n$ matrices) are also linearly independent.

A word of warning: I wouldn't really do this for more than the $2 \times 2$ case, simply because I don't want to compute a $6 \times 6$ determinant, or larger. If you insist on doing so, make sure you compute the determinant by row reduction, rather than by using minors, as it is much, much faster for slightly larger matrices.

Or, better yet, just reduce the $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix down to row-echelon form. Linear independence will be equivalent to there being a pivot in every row/column.

A second word of warning: Beware the use of determinants in general when learning linear algebra. You should strive for some understanding, and when you have the determinant, the magical linear algebra function that grants people wishes, you may find it becomes a bit a crutch! It is perfectly possible to figure out linear independence of matrices without having to use determinants, and I think it's helpful in the long run if you figure out determinant-free alternatives.

Comment: Now I think it follows from $m_1,...,m_n^2$ are linearly independent iff  the vectors $v_1,...,v_n^2$ are linearly independent, where $v_i$ is the vector form of $m_i$.  (also recall $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is of dimension $n^2$

Comment: That's right; this is because the function that maps vectors to their coordinate vectors with respect to a basis is an isomorphism, hence both linear independence and spanning properties are perfectly preserved.